# Angular 9 FormModule Unit Testog

Tags: javascript

So I have an @Input form: FormGroup.

Unit Testing

```
    describe('Component', () => {
      let component: Component;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component>;
      let apiService: ApiService;
      let fb: FormBuilder = new FormBuilder();
    
      beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [Component, TranslatePipeMock],
          imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
          providers: [
            ChangeDetectorRef,
            { provide: FormBuilder, useValue: fb },
            {
              provide: ApiService,
              useValue: apiServiceStub,
            },
            {
              provide: TranslateService,
              userValue: translateServiceStub,
            },
          ],
          schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
        }).compileComponents();
      });

  beforeEach(() => {
   apiLookupService = TestBed.inject(ApiLookupService);
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InputWhtComponent);
   fb = TestBed.inject(FormBuilder);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;

    const expectedForm = fb.group({
      isWithholdingTaxEnabled: new FormControl(true),
    });
    component.form = expectedForm;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    });
```

But i am having this error right now,
**No value accessor for form control with name: 'isWithholdingTaxEnabled'**

Comment: might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718077/no-value-accessor-for-form-control-with-name-for-mat-select-controls

Comment: what about this? i have a <div> with <div [formGroup]="this.form.get('custInformation')"/> 
and the error come out as
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'custName' of undefined

Comment: using `this` inside HTML templates is too dangerous

Comment: what should i use then?
create a formgroup in component and bind to HTML ?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't use forms extensively in angular

Comment: hmm but how do i write unit testing for that?